# Get All XML ChildNodes of Specific Type

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmldocument

Given the following code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(filename);
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
```

What is the most efficient way to get all the child nodes of `root` that are of type "item". There can be more than one element of that type. But most elements are of other types.

I know I can do this:

```
root["item"];
```

But that only returns a single element. How can I do the same thing but return all elements of that type?

Thanks!

Comment: if _item_ is the tagname of the element, `root.getElementsByTagName` may suit your needs

Comment: Yep, I don't know how efficient this approach is, but it certainly seems to do what I need.

Comment: It costs like a tree traversal, so it's proportional to tree node number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(filename);
    var nodes = doc.SelectNodes("/root/item");
```

You can test different XPaths [here](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output).

But, in my opinion, you are better off with [Linq2XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx).

Comment: My question was about getting all the child nodes of the `root` variable in my code snippet of a particular type. And other than you probably liking the syntax of LINQ to XML, why is it better?

Comment: The snippet I provided is of the same type as yours, I only modified the last line. As for Linq2XML, Microsoft goes over differencies [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387021.aspx). In Linq2XML your snippet would look like
`XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("");
doc.Root.Elements("item");`

Comment: Actually, if it works the way I need, it would be `root.SelectNodes("item")`.